# Deploying multiple Rails apps on the same domain at different paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I've got two Rails apps on my box, one located at `/opt/app1` and the other at `/opt/app2`. Each of these applications only needs a single route and a single controller action. What I'd like to do is configure nginx so that people who navigate to www.example.com will hit app1 and people who navigate to www.example.com/app2 will hit app2.

To summarize: different Rails app, same domain, without using subdomains.

I've been looking around for how to do this, but so far no luck. Here's my basic nginx setup for just the first app. Any ideas what I could add to get things working for my second app?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root /opt/app1/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Phusion Passenger documentation tells you how to do this kind of deployment

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri